# Context Handling from ListFragment - Getting NullPointerException Error Attempt to invoke virtual method...Context.getResources()'

Tags: java, android, android-context, android-listfragment

This is what I'm trying to do. I have a ListFragment that has a list of albums on the Main Activity of my app. When I longpress, I am creating a yes/no dialog and when the user presses Yes I am trying to run my delete Album method. However, I am met with this error:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
```

I suspect it has to do with the fact that I am accessing the context outside of the Activity's onCreate() method or something similar. I've been googling and trying things for hours but nothing is working. Here is the relevant code.

Look at the onItemLongClick method, error is ocurring on these commands:

```
ArrayList<Album> albumList = Album.deleteAlbum("test", appContext);
SerializableManager.saveSerializable(appContext, albumList, "albumList.ser");
```

MyFragment Class

```
package data.photoexpress;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo;
import app.photoexpress.PrimaryActivity;
import app.photoexpress.ViewAlbumActivity;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener; 

public class MyFragment extends ListFragment {

    private static Context appContext;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        appContext = getActivity().getBaseContext(); 
       // onAttach(appContext);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true); 

    }

    /*@Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);

        Activity a;

        if (context instanceof Activity){
            a=(Activity) context;
        }

    }*/

    public void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), ViewAlbumActivity.class);
        getActivity().startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    }

      @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
      public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        ListView listView = getListView();
        listView.setLongClickable(true);
        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener (new OnItemLongClickListener () { 

            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Log.e(".", "long click detected");

                AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                dialog.setTitle("Delete");
                dialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this album?");
                dialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);

                dialog.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Deleting album", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      ArrayList<Album> albumList = Album.deleteAlbum("test", appContext);
                       SerializableManager.saveSerializable(appContext, albumList, "albumList.ser");

                    }});
                dialog.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null).show();

                return true;
            } 

          }); 
      }


}
```

I have tried changing the appContext variable to many things including getActivity(), getActivity().getBaseContext() among many other things. Hopefully someone can help me

Here is the Full Stack Trace:

```
04-26 10:10:30.821: E/MotionRecognitionManager(32585): mSContextService = android.hardware.scontext.ISContextService$Stub$Proxy@bb42af2
04-26 10:10:30.821: E/MotionRecognitionManager(32585): motionService = com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@9f83543
04-26 10:10:30.821: E/MotionRecognitionManager(32585): motionService = com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@9f83543
04-26 10:10:32.241: E/.(32585): long click detected
04-26 10:10:32.891: E/AndroidRuntime(32585): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-26 10:10:32.891: E/AndroidRuntime(32585): Process: app.photoexpress, PID: 32585
04-26 10:10:32.891: E/AndroidRuntime(32585): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
04-26 10:10:32.891: E/AndroidRuntime(32585):    at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:144)
04-26 10:10:32.891: E/AndroidRuntime(32585):    at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:456)
04-26 10:10:32.891: E/AndroidRuntime(32585):    at app.photoexpress.CreateNewAlbumActivity.toastMsg(CreateNewAlbumActivity.java:55)
04-26 10:10:32.891: E/AndroidRuntime(32585):    at data.photoexpress.Album.deleteAlbum(Album.java:52)
04-26 10:10:32.891: E/AndroidRuntime(32585):    at data.photoexpress.MyFragment$1$1.onClick(MyFragment.java:80)
04-26 10:10:32.891: E/AndroidRuntime(32585):    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:173)
04-26 10:10:32.891: E/AndroidRuntime(32585):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-26 10:10:32.891: E/AndroidRuntime(32585):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
04-26 10:10:32.891: E/AndroidRuntime(32585):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
04-26 10:10:32.891: E/AndroidRuntime(32585):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-26 10:10:32.891: E/AndroidRuntime(32585):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
04-26 10:10:32.891: E/AndroidRuntime(32585):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: Just use `getActivity()` instead of your `appContext` field, which you don't really need.

Comment: I stated that I have already tried getActivity()

Comment: I meant get rid of your `appContext` field all together, because it's unnecessary. Beyond that, you need to post the complete stack trace, as the information provided is not enough to determine your problem.

Comment: @MikeM. I have added the stack trace

Comment: The NPE is coming from the `Toast` in the `CreateNewAlbumActivity.toastMsg()` method called in the  `Album.deleteAlbum()` method. You'll have to post those methods for us to be certain which `Context` reference is the cause.

Comment: I found the problem. I had this line `CreateNewAlbumActivity.toastMsg("Album deleted.");`in my Album class' deleteAlbum method. I moved it to the MyFragment onClick method and we're all good now.


I'm curious, how did you know specifically that is what was causing it? What are the telltale signs? Thank you!

Comment: Just by reading your stack trace. The method calls are listed in reverse order from where the `Exception` was thrown. You'd posted the `onClick()` method in `MyFragment`, with the call to `Album.deleteAlbum()`, but beyond that, it's not possible to know from the stack trace alone which `Context` reference was being used in the failing `Toast`.